# ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, (numpy error)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
test = np.array([20, 21, 22, 23, 22, 21])
test = test.astype(float)
result = np.zeros((1,1))
for i in range(len(test)-3):
    d = np.abs(test[i+3]-test[i])
    #print(d)
    v = 0
    for j in range(3):
        v = v + np.asscalar(
                np.abs(test[i+3-j] - test[i+3-(j+1)]))
    out = d / v
    result = np.hstack((result, out))
```

I want the result of this code to be shape of numpy array like this -> (3,1)
The normal output should originally appear as follows: [1, 0.333, 0.333]
However, when I run this code, I got an error like the title.

Comment: can't you just append to an array after declaring `result =[]` with `result=np.append(result, out)`? this will append in place though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test = np.array([20, 21, 22, 23, 22, 21])
test = test.astype(float)
```

`test` is (6,) shape array

```
result = np.zeros((1,1))
```

`result` is (1,1)

```
for i in range(len(test)-3):
    d = np.abs(test[i+3]-test[i])
    #print(d)
    v = 0
    for j in range(3):
        v = v + np.asscalar(
                np.abs(test[i+3-j] - test[i+3-(j+1)]))
    out = d / v
```

`out` is a scalar, right?

```
    result = np.hstack((result, out))
```

`hstack` turns its inputs into arrays:

```
In [4]: np.array(3).shape
Out[4]: ()
```

Trying to join a (1,1) array with a () array produces this error:

```
In [3]: np.hstack((np.zeros((1,1)), 3))
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

In general if you want to join many values in a loop, it is best to join them in a list, and make an array after.  List `append` is faster.

```
result = []
for i in range...

    result.append(out)
result = np.array(result)
```

That said, I suspect this can be calculated without loops, though I'd have take time and thoroughly understand what you are trying to do first.  The logic is not obvious.